# CSS Drop Down Menu Not Working In ie8 Drop Down Vanishes

Tags: css

I am working on the website http://www.oneluckymutt.com/ and the drop downs appear when I hover over them and then disappear when I go to click on the submenu below. The drop downs work in Chrome, FireFox, Safari but not ie8. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdowns only appear when the user is hovering over the top level list item. What is happening in Internet Explorer is that there is a small space between the li.top_level and ul.submenu. When the user hovers over this small space, they are no longer hovering over the li.top_level, and the ul disappears.

Try overlapping your li.top_level and ul.submenu to solve this problem.

```
li.top_level {
    height: 33px; /* Set a maximum height */
}

.submenu {
    top: 30px; /* Define the top position of the submenu */
}
```